# On tcl tests - how to interpret tcltest::test

Tags: tcl

I am looking at the tests in TCL source tree and I see this one in compExpr-old.test:

```
test compExpr-old-14.17 {CompilePrimaryExpr: string primary that looks like var ref} {
    expr $
} $
```

It looks wrong to me: the test runs the script `expr $` and expects the return value is "$". Is my interpretation right?

It cannot be right because `expr $` is wrong syntactically.

I checked out tcltest.tcl, the definition of `tcltest::test` is so long, wish someone can help me over here.

Comment: tl;dr: Semantic change from 8.4 to 8.5.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of the test suite you are looking at (probably some 8.4 variant?), but when I look at the whole of that test in the Tcl trunk, I see this:

```
test compExpr-old-14.17 {CompilePrimaryExpr: string primary that looks like var ref} -body {
    expr $
} -returnCodes error -match glob -result *
```

In this case, it is checking that the result is an *error* and that the value of the result (i.e., the content of the error message) glob matches with `*`, i.e., is anything (effectively ignoring it). That is, the test checks that an error is obtained from `expr $` and otherwise doesn't care.

The test you posted (which uses an older syntax for `tcltest`) won't pass on modern versions of Tcl. But in 8.4, it *did* pass; this was an area where Tcl's semantics changed between 8.4 and 8.5:

```
dkf$ tclsh8.4
% expr $
$
% exit
```

```
dkf$ tclsh8.5
% expr $
invalid character "$"
in expression "$"
% exit
```

---

Quick guide to Tcltest test cases: The `-body` describes a scrip to run, the `-returnCode` can be used to select whether normal results or errors are expected, the `-result` can be used to say what string to expect as a result of the body script, and `-match` can be used to pick an alternate matching scheme than the default (exact string equality). There's also `-constraints` for specifying preconditions on a test, `-setup` for doing setup code, and `-cleanup` for cleanup code. The two leading mandatory arguments are the name of the test (which must be unique within a test suite for your own sanity) and a short description of the test, used in reporting of failures.

In the old syntax (used in much of Tcl's test suite because updating it is a ton of boring work), you instead had the same two mandatory arguments, then an optional list of constraints (as for `-constraints`), then a mandatory body (as for `-body`), then the mandatory string to match for equality (as for `-result`). Less flexible, but not too hard to understand.

Comment: Thanks Donal, always.

The test is indeed from 8.4, but I have a hard time to take why "expr $" is valid, I will ask in a new question because of the format restriction in comment.