# Why is "expr $" valid in tcl8.4?

Tags: tcl

This is derived from [On tcl tests - how to interpret tcltest::test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40490079/on-tcl-tests-how-to-interpret-tcltesttest).

Here is from TCL8.4 man page:

> [7] **Variable substitution.**
>       If a word contains a dollar-sign (“`$`”) followed by one of the forms described below, then Tcl performs variable substitution: the dollar-sign and the following characters are replaced in the word by the value of a variable. Variable substitution may take any of the following forms:
>
> `$name`
>       *Name* is the name of a scalar variable; the name is a sequence of one or more characters that are a letter, digit, underscore, or namespace separators (two or more colons).

So a single `$` without characters like letter, digit, underscore or colon should be a syntax error.

Or it actually is a TCL parser bug but because there is no such real world script, so we get away with it?

Sorry if I seem crazily picky, just want to understand.

Comment: That manual page is _incredibly_ rules-lawyer-y. If it doesn't _say_ it is an error, it _isn't_ an error and defaults to just being nothing special at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carefully note the wording of the variable substitution rules:

> If a word contains a dollar-sign ("$") **followed by** one of the forms described below

This specifically means that if a word contains a `$` but is not followed by valid forms for variable names then it is just the literal character `$` because no **substitutions** have occurred. Again note that I carefully bolded the word "substitution".

In tcl, the `$` rule is not a rule for identifying variables like in Perl or PHP. It is a rule for replacing one string with another (think of it as a simplified `s/var/value/` operator).

You can try out the following:

```
set foo hello

puts $foo        // prints hello
puts hello$foo   // prints hellohello (note the "contains" wording of the rule)
puts $           // prints $
puts hello$      // prints hello$
puts hello$hello // errors out about $hello not existing
```

So `$` alone is not a syntax error.

What have changed is perhaps the expression parser. But for that you don't consult substitution rules, you need to read the man page for `expr` (I've read both the 8.4 and 8.6 man pages and there's nothing about bareword strings so it's probably a bug in pre-8.6 versions of expr)

Comment: It should be noted that while tcl has only 13 syntax rules the rules are very accurate. And I mean "accurate" in the mathematical sense - every word of each definition have meaning. A lot of tcl's behavior is emergent - they appear by interactions of the rules with each other rather than specified on their own.